# Problems in unit tests using NestJS Schedule and Jest FakeTimers

Tags: jestjs, cron, nestjs

I registered a CronJob that runs every midnight through the Schedule provided by NestJS, and wrote a test to see if it is called on time.

I know that CronJob is registered when the Nest application is bootstrapped, so I set the time through Jest's FakeTimers before the application was created. There were cases where it ran normally, but there were cases where it did not run as expected, so I couldn't find the reason and asked the question....

### Passed Test Case

Before creating the application, the time was set to **2023.12.25 23:59:59**, and after creation, the specific time was added and it was successful.

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

describe('BatchService Test', () => {
  let app: NestApplication, registry: SchedulerRegistry;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date(2023, 11, 25, 23, 59, 59));

    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        MyBatchService,
      ]
    }).compile();
    
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    registry = module.get(SchedulerRegistry);

    await app.init();
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('AllBatchServiceTest', () => {
    describe('Test1', () => {
      test('It Must Call', () => {
        const registeredBatch = registry.getCronJob(MY_BATCH_NAME);

        const expectedLastDate = new Date(2023, 11, 26, 0, 0, 0);
        
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1002);

        expect(registeredBatch).not.toBe(null);
        expect(registeredBatch.lastExecution).toEqual(expectedLastDate);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

### Failed Test Case

Change the time within the **beforeEach()** or **test()** paragraph before executing the test, the last execution time will appear as null.

However, search through **SchedulerRegistry**, can see that the time to be performed next has been updated normally.

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

describe('BatchService Test', () => {
  let app: NestApplication, registry: SchedulerRegistry;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date(2023, 11, 25, 23, 50, 0));

    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        MyBatchService,
      ]
    }).compile();
    
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    registry = module.get(SchedulerRegistry);

    await app.init();
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('AllBatchServiceTest', () => {
    describe('Test1', () => {
      test('It Must Call', () => {
        jest.setSystemTime(new Date(2023, 11, 25, 23, 59, 59));

        const registeredBatch = registry.getCronJob(MY_BATCH_NAME);

        const expectedLastDate = new Date(2023, 11, 26, 0, 0, 0);
        
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1002);

        expect(registeredBatch).not.toBe(null);
        expect(registeredBatch.lastExecution).toEqual(expectedLastDate);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

### When i Log Batch.nextDate()

`DateTime { ts: 2023-12-27T00:00:00.000+09:00 }`

I don't understand why I'm getting this result...